# Terminal command for WhatsChrome

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04, whatsapp

[WhatsChrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatschrome/bgkodfmeijboinjdegggmkbkjfiagaan?hl=en) is a lovely little desktop app that links to my Whatsapp.
 What is the Ubuntu terminal command to launch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the one

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=bgkodfmeijboinjdegggmkbkjfiagaan
```